# How to install gems based on Gemfile.lock (without Gemfile)

Tags: ruby, bundler

Usually, people will use `bundle install` to install gems. But it require Gemfile and Gemfile.lock(optional).

My situation is a little different. I only have Gemfile.lock. So how can I install all these gems based on `bundle` command.

I tried `bundle install --deployment`. But I got **Could not locate Gemfile** error.

---

OK. I asked this question in bundler github issues. Their member gave me a good answer: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5293#issuecomment-269978731

For summary -- **I CAN NOT DO THAT**

I gave up to run `bundle install` with Gemfile.lock only. But I still need to solve my problem. And in my Gemfile, I don't have any special options like groups, platforms, install conditionals. So I wrote a [script(gem)](https://rubygems.org/gems/gemfile_lock_to_gemfile) to revert the Gemfile.lock to Gemfile for my docker image.

[SOLVED]

Comment: did you consider reading the `gemfile.lock` and reverse-engineering the `gemfile`? Bundler is designed to use gemfiles, I don't recommend you fight it.

Comment: @Myst I am trying either reverse gemfile.lock -> gemfile OR bundle install directly via gemfile.lock. It's because I only have Gemfile.lock right now. The Gemfile will `require` some external Gemfile in another repo. So when I build my docker image. I only have the generated Gemfile.lock. What should I do?

Comment: maybe download a local copy every time you run the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deployment mode](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html#DEPLOYMENT-MODE) of a bundler.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before. But I got `Could not locate Gemfile` error.

Answer (score 1):

With only `gemfile.lock`, you can run

```
bundle install --deployment
```

The only catch is that this command installs gems to the vendor/bundle instead of your normal gem bundle path. it is so because it is expected to be used only in production.

It works well all the same though.

Comment: I saw this solution in other thread. But when I try to use it. I got error: `Could not locate Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply running the gem install directly in your terminal? That way you won't need to use a Gemfile at all.

For example, with the devise gem, you can just run `$ gem install devise` in your terminal and that will install the devise gem without adding it to your Gemfile.

Comment: I know I can do that. But I am trying to build a docker image. Which I hope I can re-use my local Gemfile.lock. So that I don't have to manually add bunch of gem install commands.