# No gem file in my Ruby on Rails project, bundle install/update doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, centos, passenger

I am working on a project in which Gemfile is not present.
That project is working fine on production server having Apache with passenger.
But, Bundle install and bundle update does not work when I try try to start project in development environment. How to get that project working in development environment?

Comment: What is the error message that comes up when you run bundle?

Comment: Any reason for not following conventions?

Comment: @DormeoES, Error: Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: @Ruslan do not know the reason why the developer who was handling this project did so.

Comment: Is there a Gemfile or Gemfile.lock in the production environment?

Comment: In passenger config, check which gemset is being used for your application.

Comment: @RolandStuder no Gemfile, Gemfile.lock is present in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone from systems engineering can tell you, where the Gems were defined, You can reverse engineer a Gemfile from the contents of `Gemfile.lock`.

Or you can try to run your project by using this command, after you copied the Gemfile.lock from production, also put an empty Gemfile, as the bundler requires it.

```
bundle install --deployment
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359249/how-to-install-gems-based-on-gemfile-lock-without-gemfile), but sooner or later you will need the Gemfile.